# How can I get the String values of all of the <p> tags on a web page in Java?

Tags: java, android, html

I need to find a way to extract the String values of the `<p>` tags of a website, using Java.  I've seen some people do similar things Javascript, but I was hoping to find a way to do it using Java.  I'm trying to make an app for a website, and all of the news posts are inside of `<p>` tags instead of an RSS feed.

Thanks!

Comment: Jsoup would be a good starting point.

Comment: A google search for "Java HTML parser" will give you lots of choices.  Here is a collection: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to perform the task, with it the task can be as easy as

```
for(Element e: doc.getElementsByTag("p")) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```